# Sort files in a specific way

Tags: python, algorithm, function, sorting, lambda

There are a list of files in my directory, and now I aim to save the content to a database. Prior to that however, I need to sort them in the right order.

The current ordering is as follows:

```
['8.txt', '8-0.txt', '8-1.txt', '8-2.txt', '8-0-0.txt', '8-0-1.txt',
 '8-0-2.txt', '8-0-3.txt', '8-1-0.txt', '8-2-0.txt', '8-2-1.txt']
```

And I wish to have them order as follows:

```
['8.txt', '8-0.txt', '8-0-0.txt', '8-0-1.txt', '8-0-2.txt', '8-0-3.txt', 
 '8-1.txt', '8-1-0.txt', '8-2.txt', '8-2-0.txt', '8-2-1.txt']
```

Basically, think of these files as posts, comments and replies.

The first file '8.txt' without any dash is the original post. Followed by that we have a group of comments, e.g. '8-0.txt', '8-1.txt', etc, i.e. one dash in the file names. Finally, for each comment, there could potentially be some replies, which has the name format, '8-2-0.txt', '8-2-1.txt', (2 dashes).

While I know the brute force way can definitely do this kind of ordering, I wonder if there are any Pythonic ways (e.g. some lambda functions in the function for sorting)

For now we can assume there are only up to 2 dashes in the filenames, i.e. no more than 3 levels of hierarchy.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty is sorting things correctly that are similar to

```
8-1-12.txt   # simply removing non digits ==> 8112 
8-11-2.txt   # simply removing non digits ==> 8112 as well
```

Easy solution is to leverage `tuple` - sorting:

```
f = ['8.txt', '8-0.txt', '8-0-0.txt', '8-0-1.txt', '8-0-2.txt', '8-0-3.txt', 
     '8-1.txt', '8-1-0.txt', '8-2.txt', '8-2-0.txt', '8-2-1.txt','8-12-0.txt',
     '8-1-12.txt', '8-11-2.txt']

def to_tuple(text):
    """Extract all numbers from file as tuple (8,1,3) ... etc."""
    return tuple(map(int, text.split(".")[0].split("-") ))

f.sort(key = to_tuple)
print(f)
```

Output:

```
['8.txt', '8-0.txt', '8-0-0.txt', '8-0-1.txt', '8-0-2.txt', '8-0-3.txt', 
 '8-1.txt', '8-1-0.txt', '8-1-12.txt', 
 '8-2.txt', '8-2-0.txt', '8-2-1.txt', 
 '8-11-2.txt', '8-12-0.txt']
```

If your names contain things that are not int-conversible you need to use `try: except:` and refine the `to_tuple()` function to handle your names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Natural sorting](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Natural_sorting) includes that as well as others.